# What is a right bijection between $S$ and $T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have the sets $S = \{2^{n}3^{m} \mid m,n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ and $T = \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. I need to define a bijection between this two sets. I tried to use basic operations such as $2^{n}3^{m}\to n+m$ and $2^{n}3^{m}\to mn$ but this fails to be bijections. Please any suggestion would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: $2^n3^m\mapsto 2^{n-1}(2m-1)$

Comment: There's a natural bijection between $S$ and $\Bbb Z_{\ge0}^2$. Do you know a bijection between $\Bbb Z_{\ge0}^2$ and $\Bbb Z^+$? Can you combine these?

Comment: What do you mean "right bijection?"  There are uncountably many bijections between these two sets.  What makes one the right one?

Comment: Right means correct or suitable, although it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

One way is this:
$$
\begin{align}
f(1) & = \min S \\
f(2) & = \min(S\smallsetminus \{f(1)\}) \\
f(3) & = \min(S\smallsetminus\{f(1),f(2)\}) \\
f(4) & = \min(S\smallsetminus \{f(1),f(2),f(3)\}) \\
& \,\,\, \vdots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see that  this argument do not use the structure of the set $S$ except  for the infiniteness. Is this argument applicable to any infinite subset $S\subset \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Comment: @DIEGOR.:  yes, this works for any infinite subset.  Some will complain that it does not give an explicit formula, but that is not required.  In this case there is one.

Comment: @DIEGOR. This solution gives a complicated function of $m$ and $n$ rather than one with a nice pattern, and in some contexts it would make sense to find fault with it because of that. At the same time, the fact that something like this works for every infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ is something one should be aware of.

Comment: @DIEGOR. English-speaking mathematicians use the word "any" too much. "Does this work for any infinite set?" can mean "Is it true that for any infinite set, no matter which one, this works?" or it can mean "Is there any infinite set for which this works?" In the first example, "any" means "every" and in the second it means "some". It's easy to disambiguate by writing "every" or "some" instead.

Comment: @RossMillikan : $\qquad \uparrow \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

I would start from T instead if starting from S.
First you can call all éléments of S with parameters : S(m,n)
Then you can have a fonction f :
f(T) --> S
00 -> S(0,0)
01 -> S(1,0)
02 -> S(0,1)
03 -> S(1,1)
04 -> S(2,0)
05 -> S(0,2)
06 -> S(2,1)
07 -> S(1,2)
08--> S(2,2)
09--> S(3,0)
10--> S(0,3)
...

This way, f is a bijection from T to S. And you know that the inverse of f, from S to T, exist.

Hope it helps